How is the out keyword able to assign back to a pointer?
The original snippet is easy to understand:
ref var l = ref Output22[0][i];
ref var r = ref Output22[1][i];

SpuReverb.Process(ref Reverb, l, r, out l, out r);

However, this using & also works:
var l = &output22[0][i]; // float*
var r = &output22[1][i];

SpuReverb.Process(ref Reverb, *l, *r, out *l, out *r);

Isn't *l supposed to be the value of l, i.e. not a reference?
Yet it works just like the original version, can you explain why?

Haven't used pointers that way in C#, but in C++ *l always returns a reference, not a value.

ditto for me ... and I also think *l is a pointer (the address of the variable), not a deferenced pointer (the value of the variable)

(unless operator* is overloaded, but that doesn't exist in C#)

*l indeed returns a reference to the pointed variable. Otherwise, how would dereferencing and assigning like this work in C#:
float a = 1;
float* l = &a;

// To prevent optimizations
System.Console.WriteLine(a); // Prints 1

*l = 2;

System.Console.WriteLine(a); // Prints 2

On .NET 8, the code above generates the same IL as the following block using ref variables, as demonstrated on Compiler Explorer:
float a = 1;
ref float l = ref a;

System.Console.WriteLine(a);

l = 2;

System.Console.WriteLine(a);

